# If we are using Dropbox Datastore API, can I encrypt the entire data I store there?

Tags: dropbox-api

If we are storing the data in Dropbox using Datastore APIs, can we encrypt the entire set of files we store, so that only app can understand that data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Dropbox Datastore API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/datastore) is an old and now retired API which is no longer servicing requests and so can no longer be used.

For uploading/downloading files to/from Dropbox, you should be using [Dropbox API v2](https://www.dropbox.com/developers).

When doing so, yes, you can encrypt the data before you upload it. The Dropbox API will just accept whatever raw data you upload, which you can then download and decrypt later as desired.